# VideoView as an Item in list view creates an artifact in upper and lower in the list view. How to solve that?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

Hello i am developing the list view which is having the custom layout with the imageview, AudioPlayeer and Video view. I am Displaying and Hiding the two of the above view at a once in  the item.

However i can Display the image and `AudioPlayer`(custom with some buttons) in the item perfectly but when `i tried to display videoView it will render the view on the upper and down side of the list view.` Is there any solution to Display `VideoView` as an Item in `ListvieW`.

What is the solution of Displaying the `VideoView` inside the `Listview` in android?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Henrique : no i am still searching there are some debates in which the programmers are suggesting not to Do it. But i have to make the videoView as an item in the list view. I am still searching for that.. If you get anything about that Do let me know

Comment: Let us know if you are ever able to find a way to do this, would go a long way, thanks

Comment: Should I say me too here?? ;-)
I'll post an answer once I found out. For now I think the only way is to not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution which I got now, is that you can't use both of them together. Since Listview deletes and recreates the objects while scrolling, for memory management.

The solution is to either refrain from Using videoView in the ListView or use A ScrollView instead of ListView. In the second solution, you can put LinearLayouts in successtion in a Layout and put the layout into the ScrollView. This method will work only if you don't have too many videoview to be shown, or else it'll lag while scrolling.